# Very fast digital gates

Tags: digital-logic

Does someone know a digital gates (inverter, buffer, nand, and, or, nor, etc...) that can go from 0V to 5V in about 1ns?

I have check TTL, but they are not so fast.

Ideally, I should found it in Farnell, Digikey, Mouser, etc...

Alain.

Comment: You should check out these questions: [1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2925/cheap-solid-equipment-wire-for-breadboard-from-online-shop), [2](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/94841/how-can-a-small-device-produce-two-million-volts) and finally [3](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=shopping). I got them from [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=shopping) while also doing a ctrl+f for "closed".

Comment: why do you want a gate that fast?

Comment: If you just want a fast rise time pulse e.g. to characterize an oscilloscope, there are other ways to generate one.

Comment: @pericynthion No idea whether this would help the OP, but what would you suggest to generate a fast rise time pulse?

Comment: @user2233709 Jim Williams has a famous design - Appendix D of [this app note](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/application-note/an47fa.pdf) and google "avalanche pulse generator" for various related designs, both DIY and low-cost off-the-shelf.

Comment: What you are looking for isn't exactly a gate, but a very strong output driver. Driving a cable from 0V to 5V within 1ns is much harder than making a GHz logic.

Answer (score 5):

Emitter coupled logic is that you want, like the https://www.digikey.co.uk/product-detail/en/MC10EP08DTG/MC10EP08DTGOS-ND/920778?curr=gbp&WT.z_cid=ref_octopart_dkc_buynow&site=us

Why do you need it to go that fast?

If you want your circuit to actually go at GHz speeds, you'll need to take a lot of things into account other than just the chip.

Comment: ...things like controlled impedance PCB layout and line termination; and these ECL systems are power-hungry. Bear in mind the speed of light is about 1ns per 20-30cm, so in that realm cables and pcb traces are no longer just ideal wires, they are transmission lines and delay lines.

Comment: OP asked for a pulse going from 0 to 5 V. ECL levels are classically from about -2 to -1 V, or +3 to +4 V if using them as "PECL". (Levels are very rough, but in any case the difference between low and high is ~800-1000 mV, not 5 V)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your first response. I need such speed in order to generate a very fast dV/dt (>1500V/us). The target is to make some characterize some device in extreme condition.

Comment: Hello again! Yes I know that for such speed, I should be very strict in the design.

Comment: @ThePhoton is correct that the vdiff is only 800mV, but it looks like that may work in your design, because it can switch in 130ps, giving a rise time of 6000V/us

Answer (score 2):

[Potato Semiconductor](http://www.potatosemi.com/) (yes, really) has some 74-family parts with sub-nanosecond rise/fall times.

Comment: "It looks like your pulse was generated on a potato"